# Multiple input variables - can only get 1 variable to pass

Tags: sql-server-2005, parameters, dynamic-sql

```
declare @strSQL nvarchar(max)
set @strSQL = '
select * from HumanResources.Department where Name = @Name1
union all
select * from HumanResources.Department where Name = @Name2
'

Exec sp_executesql @strSQL, 
  N'@Name1 nvarchar(max)', 'Engineering', 
  N'@Name2 nvarchar(max)', 'Tool Design'
```

This is a silly example, but it will sort out my problem (Adventureworks demo). How do I get the second parameter (@Name2) into the sp_ExecuteSQL please, it only picks up the first parameter (@Name1)?

Comment: Your statement should be `EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL, N'@Name1 NVARCHAR(MAX),@Name2 NVARCHAR(MAX)', N'Engineering', N'Tool Design'`;

Comment: brilliant thanks! could you post as answer pls